# How to narrow down count query by a finite time frame?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I am identifying more than 1 submission by user for a particular form:

```
select userid, form_id, count(*)
from table_A
group by userid, form_id
having count(userid) > 1
```

However, I am trying to see which users are submitting more than 1 form within a 5 second timeframe (We have a field for the submission timestamp in this table).  How would I narrow this query down by that criteria?

Comment: Can you provide Sample input data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nikotromus

You've not provided a lot of details about your schema and other columns available, nor about what / how and where this information will be used.

However if you want to do it "live" so compare results in your time against current timestamp it would look something like:

```
SELECT userid, form_id, count(*)
  FROM table_A
 WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND,YourColumnWithSubmissionTimestamp, getdate()) <= 5
GROUP BY userid, form_id
HAVING count(userid) > 1
```

Comment: Why not just use one datediff between `YourColumnWithSubmissionTimestamp` and `getdate()`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - you mean something like this in WHERE: DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19000101', getdate() - YourColumnWithSubmissionTimestamp)? I'm not able to test the idea right now, thus posted something that I would expect will work. Thanks for comment though!

Comment: No, I mean something like this: `WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND,YourColumnWithSubmissionTimestamp, getdate()) <= 5`

Comment: @ZoharPeled - ahh of course, yes your are totally right. Thanks for good point :)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add to the group by `DATEDIFF(Second, '2017-01-01', SubmittionTimeStamp) / 5`.
This will group records based on the userid, form_id and a five seconds interval:

```
select userid, form_id, count(*)
from table_A
group by userid, form_id, datediff(Second, '2017-01-01', SubmittionTimeStamp) / 5
having count(userid) > 1
```

Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908362/in-sql-server-2014-how-do-you-group-by-any-time-based-interval/41918973#41918973) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: This will group them within five second interval. What if one record was at the end of one interval and the other at the very beginning of the next interval?

Comment: That's a good point. Didn't think about it. However I think morb1d just might came up with the simplest solution. One we should probably both think about.... That is, if the OP means to get the users in the last 5 seconds.

Comment: That'll work only for within 5 seconds from now, right?

Comment: Yours is what OP wanted. :)

Comment: I hope that's also what they need... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` to form groups of rows that are within 5 seconds of each other and then do aggregation on them:

```
select distinct userid,
    form_id
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(val) over (
            order by t.submission_timestamp
            ) as grp
    from (
        select t.*,
            case 
                when datediff(ms, lag(t.submission_timestamp, 1, t.submission_timestamp) over (
                            order by t.submission_timestamp
                            ), t.submission_timestamp) > 5000
                    then 1
                else 0
                end val
        from your_table t
        ) t
    ) t
group by userid,
    form_id,
    grp
having count(*) > 1;
```

See this answer for more explanation:

- [Group records by consecutive dates when dates are not exactly consecutive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721245/group-records-by-consecutive-dates-when-dates-are-not-exactly-consecutive/41721401#41721401)

Comment: I find it nice that we both are recycling answers. Very enviromnetal :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - :)

Comment: Got this error when I tried to run it...    Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Comment: @nikotromus - the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds. If you try changing it to seconds in `datediff(seconds,..). . . > 5`. For seconds the range is 68 years. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `exists` to get the users:

```
select userid, form_id
from table_A a
where exists (select 1
              from table_A a2
              where a2.userid = a.userid and a2.timestamp >= a.timestamp and a2.timestamp < dateadd(second, 5, a.timestamp
            );
```

If you want a count, you can just add `group by` and `count(*)`.